# Is there any shortcut for debugging client/server application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create a client/server game(C#).
I find myself doing this routine a lot: running the main server application(by pressing F5), and then debugging the first and the second clients(by right clicking on the client project and selecting start new instance for each client).
Is there any shortcut for this routine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right-click the solution, click Properties, select Startup Project, and set both projects to run.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that trick, btw, anyway to start 2 client instances?

Comment: This is the most useful answer ever!